# how to use same store in different pages in Extjs

Tags: java, extjs4

My requirement is I have search criteria page and on click on search button i am getting search criteria data and i want to use that data in store and the on click on search button page redirect to chart page. How to use first page data to second page.

i want to use that data for displaying chart using store.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

declare a global variable variable in app.js

```
 var gVar = {};
```

add you store to global variable and use that

```
 gVar.cStore=yourStore;
```

Comment: thanks for replay But On search Criteria I am getting response and all the data which i need are in response. How to use that response data to store root. Thanks in advance.